# iterative closet point - MEX Matlab

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-2015, mex

I am using VS 2015, MATLAB 2016a, and I am working on this project: 
http://www.cvlibs.net/software/libicp/ (iterative closet point).

However, I get troubles at adding BOOST folder to the system. 
When I run make.m to create the MEX file in matlab, I got something like this:

C:\boost_1_63_0\boost/mpl/aux_/msvc_never_true.hpp(17): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
include file: 'boost/mpl/aux_/config/msvc.hpp': No such file or directory

I don't know how to solve this problem, please help me. Thank you very much

Comment: Have you seen/tried [this](https://github.com/peterbrook/libicp-net) (not sue if it's different)? And have you addressed this question to the original developers?

Comment: Hi horchler, I just tried your link and it has the same problem. I don't know why stdio.h we don't need full path? Can we do this for external folder?